# hibernate - force properties not to be loaded from database

Tags: hibernate, properties

Is there a way to mark certain properties not to retrieve at all?

I have a unique pepper row inside my user table and I don't want to load this pepper and the hashed password if a User is retrieved.

I don't have any needs for it on the remote client and so I want to make sure it is not accidently passed to it.

If i need to regenerate or change a password at the application server I can retrieve the pepper via a named query.

Comment: doesnt creating a dto for transfer which doesn't have a pepper and passwordhash solce your problem?

Comment: It would, but i am sending the Entity classes to the client. I currently set those values to null before sending.

Comment: sending entities causes problems sooner than you think ( http://stackoverflow.com/q/1688473/671619 ) and also viewdata is often different from entities

Comment: DTO's seem to be a good idea, and i will definetly consider using those in the client view (shop). But in my database back-end using entities saved a lot of programming time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly implement an Interceptor and override the `onLoad` Method: [More Information on Hibernate Interceptors Here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html#objectstate-interceptors)

I have used this strategy overriding the onFlushDirty and onSave Methods to update Timestamp fields. I have never used it during `onLoad`.

Here is an example Interceptor based on a similar one I have used (Not Tested):

> ```
> public final class PepperInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
>
>     /** The Value to set as the Pepper field when loading from the DB. */
>     private static final String DEFAULT_PEPPER = "[PROTECTED-PEPPER]";
>
>     @Override
>     public boolean onLoad(final Object entity, final Serializable id, final Object[] currentState,
>             final Object[] previousState, final String[] propertyNames, final Type[] types) {
>
>
>         if (entity instanceof User) {
>             for (int i = 0; i < propertyNames.length; i++) {
>                 if (propertyNames[i].equalsIgnoreCase("pepper")) {
>                     currentState[i] = DEFAULT_PEPPER;
>                 }
>             }
>
>             return true;
>         }
>         return super.onLoad(entity, id, currentState, previousState, propertyNames, types);
>     }
> ```
>
> }

---

EDIT:

Thinking about this further, you would have to ensure the value is never overwritten with the `DEFAULT_PEPPER`, possibly using something like `updatable=false` in the column definition of your Entity Class

Comment: Will have a look at this but it looks pretty overhead especially if there are more Entities to control. +1 for the `update=false`!

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate allows for overriding the generated sql as required.

http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Hibernate_Annotations_Reference_Guide/entity-hibspec-customsql.html

The @Loader annotation may be of use.